# Do I really need drawRect() in custom UIView?

Tags: ios, uiview, drawrect

I am new to iOS and trying to understand the use for drawRect() in custom UIViews, so I have simple custom view which I initialize from code.I want to update its colors for instance and I see two approaches as shown below. Which one should I use and why?

```
//VController
CustomView *cv = [[CustomView alloc] initWithFrame:...]
...
[cv updateColors];

//CustomView
-(id) initWithFrame {}
-(id) initWithCoder  {}
-(void) updateColors(UIColor *color){  ----(1)
  ...Draw here with new color ...
   view1.backgroundColor = color;
   view2.backgroundColor = color;

 }
- (void) drawRect{
 ... draw here with new color ... ---------(2)
   view1.backgroundColor = color;
   view2.backgroundColor = color;
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If *all* you want to do is change the background color of this view or some of its subviews, you absolutely should *not* misuse `drawRect:` for this. `drawRect:` is for when you want to draw the view (i.e. its content) when the system believes its needs refreshing; it is called at many and unpredictable times, and you don't need that - you just need to change the background color, a *feature* of the view, on demand. Similarly `drawRect:` is *not* the place to perform management of subviews.

But if you *are* going to draw the view's content (e.g. the view displays a circle and you need to draw that circle to portray the view) then you *must* use `drawRect:` for that; it is the *only* place where the view gets a chance to draw itself.

Comment: If I had a view and it's sub layers needed to be removed and re-added again, is it ok to do that in drawRect? I currectly use this way, because I don't have other ways to trigger the re-adding.

Comment: @Wingzero Absolutely not. Adding and removal of subviews has nothing _whatever_ to do with the drawing of the content of the view.

Comment: alright, when I got the project, there is a lot of code doing such things, I guess it is because the developer is quite lazy, so only call `addSubview` will handle all tasks. I guess I have to stop following this wrong way

Comment: One more question, is it ok to perform animations inside drawRect? If not, what are the good places?